# Geoencode Address to GPS Coordinates

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation, yahoo-maps

I'm looking to geoencode an address and convert it to GPS Coordinates.  Basically,

```
var address;

//  Google/Yahoo/whatever program to convert address to GPS coordinates

var output=xx.xxxxxxx,xx.xxxxxxx
```

I've researched Google and Yahoo APIs, but can't seem to get their codes to work in my Google Gadget.  Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Both Google API and Yahoo API do this, so my advice is to post your code that is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I did for my address-to-gps-coords needs:

```
function get_coords(address)
{
    var gc      = new google.maps.Geocoder(),
        opts    = { 'address' : address };

    gc.geocode(opts, function (results, status)
    {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
        {   
            var loc     = results[0].geometry.location,
                lat     = loc.$a,
                long    = loc.ab;

            // Success.  Do stuff here.
        }
        else
        {
            // Ruh roh.  Output error stuff here
        }
    });
}
```

Then you call it like `get_coords('1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW Washington, DC 20500')` and it'll return the latitude and longitude.

You'll need to supply your own Google Maps API key to make it work, of course.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I help to maintain one API called [LiveAddress](http://smartystreets.com/products/liveaddress-api) which does this. Much easier to use than Google/Yahoo's APIs, and without the restrictive Terms of Service which prohibit requests *en masse*, storing the results, or using the data without showing a map or by automation.

Here's a complete example, using [this sample wrapper function](https://github.com/smartystreets/LiveAddressSamples/blob/master/javascript/liveaddress.js):

```
LiveAddress.init(123456789); // your API key here
LiveAddress.geocode("address goes here", function(geo) {
    // You can also pass in an array of addresses,
    // the ID of a DOM element containing the address,
    // or an array of IDs
    console.log(geo);
});
```

Individual coordinates are found in `geo.lat` and `geo.lon`, with the combined string "lat, lon" format in `geo.coords`. You can also obtain the precision of the data with `geo.precision`.

Answer (score 1):

I did this and worked perfect:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var dir1 = "5th ave, new york";
var google_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=";
var sensor = "&sensor=false";
var resultado;

function myFunction(){ 

    $.getJSON(
        google_url+dir1+sensor,
        function(result){
            $( "body" ).append( "Latitude: " + JSON.stringify(result.results[0].geometry.bounds.northeast.lat) )
            $( "body" ).append( "Longitude: " + JSON.stringify(result.results[0].geometry.bounds.northeast.lng) )  
    });

}
```